# How to run a Testng suite present in a jar file through command prompt by saying "java -jar selenium.jar"

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, testng

Am running a jar file "Selenium.jar" from command prompt. Below is my main class where am saying it to run a TestNG suite "Suite1.xml" from a path in my directory.The above mentioned jar file also contains "Suite1.xml". Now my question is how can i run that "Suite1.xml" present in jar file when i say "java -jar selenium.jar".

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      login =args[0];
      user = args[1];
      pwd =  args[2];
      TestNG tng = new TestNG();
      List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
      suites.add("C:/SVN/Selenium 2.32/Suite1.xml");
      tng.setTestSuites(suites);
      tng.run();
    }
```

Comment: your terminology is confused.  a jar file is an executable, an xml file is not.  you cannot "run" an xml file.  Are you asking how to access a file inside a jar file?

Comment: @RussellUhl  yes your right i want that file to be accessed in `suites.add()` (in above code) within the jar and by the way that file is a TestNG file (Suite1.xml).

Comment: ok.  I don't know how to do that exactly, but jar files are just zip files with a different name.  You need to research "how to access content in zip file in java"